# Are the formulas not parsing in 64-bit Chrome or is it just me?

Tags: bug, status-deferred, mathjax

I don't see any formulas, just a white "placeholder" on the 64-bit version of Google Chrome. I have this problem at the university (with Chrome 64-bit as well). Is this coincidence or is there something wrong?

It certainly used to work!

Comment: Which version of Chrome? Have you tried clearing the cache?

Comment: @KennyTM: I'm using version 7.0.517.41 for Ubuntu amd64. I have cleared the cache, cookies and so on. In the lower left corner I can see that the javascripts are loading, but afterwards they don't display!

Comment: no-repro for Chrome 7 on Mac. Can anyone test on Ubuntu?

Comment: I have discovered it stopped working after the update.

Comment: http://tea.mathoverflow.net/discussion/637/report-bugs-with-latex-mathjax-rendering-here/ In the bottom, there is also someone with Ubuntu where it doesn't work!

Comment: Google Chrome 7.0.517.41 Stable and BETA on Ubuntu 10.04 work fine for me.

Comment: @Robert Smith: Is it the 32-bit or 64-bit version? I tried it on my 32-bit machine where it seems to work (with the same version), but I couldn't yet check it at home (since it might be fixed now?).

Comment: 32-bit version. Maybe it is already fixed. However, to be honest I never noticed a trouble parsing LaTeX in the way you described it.

Comment: It isn't fixed. 64-bit version doesn't work, 32-bit version works. The formulas are placed on the wrong location I have noticed, not just white placeholders. As the link to the MO-meta shows, I'm not the only one with the problem.

Comment: You should send an e-mail to the MathJax guys notifying of the bug : http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?group_id=261188&atid=1240827

Comment: I meant 'file a new bug'. What was I thinking?

Answer (score 1):

Works fine for us in Chrome 7 (current released version) on Windows.

Do you also have this problem in Firefox?

Comment: I don't have the problem in Firefox. What is the version (and 32 or 64 bit?) you have? I don't have the problem on 32-bit as well. On meta.mathoverflow, there are also other people reporting this error.

Comment: @jonas do you mean 32-bit and 64-bit *operating system* or *browser*? There are two variables here.

Comment: @Jeff: A 64-bit browser. Of course I have Ubuntu 10.04 for amd64 too.

Comment: @jonas any reason you need to use a 64-bit browser? Plugins won't work for it, and there's no performance benefit.

Comment: @Jeff: No, there is no reason (most plugins work with a wrapper). I will just use the 32-bit version then.

Comment: @jonas ok, I updated your question to make it clear that the 64-bit version is the one that has issues with MathJax

Answer (score 1):

Update to Chrome 8 beta (64bit) and your problem will be solved!

Comment: Well, maybe it does, but if it is a beta, there might be even more bugs...

Comment: @Jonas I can't see any. The 'beta' versions of chrome are quite stable.